# Haskell concat replicate inside list comprehension

Tags: haskell, replication, list-comprehension

I'm having trouble with the following exercise :

Utilizing list comprehension, define a function with the following signature:

```
reproduce :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

This function exchanges the every number in a list by x copies of itself.

eg:

```
input: reproduce[3,5,1]
output: [3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,1]
```

I have done the following:

```
reproduce :: [Int] -> [Int]
reproduce xs = [ x | x <- [1,2..10 ] , x `elem` xs , replicate x x ]
```

My line of thought was making x belong to a small interval, x had to be an element of the original list so using `elem`x would only be added if it did belong to the original list, and replicating x , x times, to get the x copies of himself.

When i try to load this function i get the following error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[Int]'
In the return type of a call of `replicate'
In the expression: replicate x x
In a stmt of a list comprehension: replicate x x
```

I have no idea how to fix this error, I'm assuming it has something to do with the `elem` part but I don't know what.

NOTE: This is a beginners exercise and thus should be solved in a simple manner.

Comment: No, as it says in the error, it has to do with `replicate x x` where Haskell expects a boolean.

Comment: And why does Haskell expect a boolean? Should i try adding == True in the `elem` verification?

Comment: Because that is the only place were the result is a Bool (i think), and thus maybe since I didn't have the == comparison, when it got to the replicate predicate it would give that error?

Comment: replicate doesn't return Bool. It's not a predicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list comprehension consists of a result expression `L` and one or more comma-separated right-hand forms `R1`, `R2`, ... arranged like this:

```
[ L | R1, R2, ... ]
```

Every right-hand side form must be either (1) a generator:

```
pattern <- expression
```

or (2) a `let` binding:

```
let pattern = expression
```

or (3) a filter condition (an expression returning a `Bool`):

```
expression
```

In your code we have three such forms. `x <- [1,2..10 ]` is a generator (case 2), `` x `elem` xs `` is a filter condition (case 3), but `replicate x x` fits none of these. And that's what the error message is about: Haskell expects the expression to have type `Bool` but `replicate` returns a list.

---

To actually solve the problem, you could start by doing this:

```
notQuiteReproduce xs = [ replicate x x | x <- xs ]
```

Now `notQuiteReproduce [3, 5, 1]` yields `[[3,3,3],[5,5,5,5,5],[1]]`. All that's left is to "flatten" the result list. This can also be done with a list comprehension but I'm reluctant to just give the solution away.

Comment: Oh, so if I change the x at the start of the comprehension to the replicate, and remove the replicate from the right hand forms, it should solve the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to "flatten" the result list in the notQuiteReproduce function? Because i think this is supposed to be done in a single function.

Comment: Ok, i will figure it out than, thank you very much for the assistance.